# Simultaneous Ajax Calls JS Returning Data Incorreclty

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitch

I am trying to put strings in an array through two different ajax calls. Divs are then created with ids of the name of string and include data about what twitch streamers are streaming from the ajax requests.

The problem is that I am struggling to do so that the element goes through the first ajax call and then goes through the second because ajax calls are asynchronous. As a result, elements in the array would go through the second ajax request before the first one was completed and try to go into divs that were not yet created.

To try to fix this, I put the second ajax request within the first one like so:

ajax request{

code that makes dis

second ajax request}

This seems to have made the elements in the array come back in the correct order, but the divs are not displaying the data from the ajax requests correctly. I have noticed that when logging the `name` variable, that only one element in the array seems to get passed through to the second ajax request.

[console log][1]

Anyway, I am still learning how to troubleshoot so any tips would be greatly appreciated.

[This is what it should look like ][2]

Below is the JS and here is a link to the codepen if that is helpful:https://codepen.io/mso122591/pen/jxNoBV

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var twichUrl = "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api";
  var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "freecodecamp", "OgamingSC2"];
  var name = "";
  var name2 = "";
  var logo = "";

  for (i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
    twitchUrl =
      "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/" +
      channels[i] +
      "?callback=?";

    twitchUrlStream =
      "https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" +
      channels[i] +
      "?callback=?";

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: twitchUrl,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonp: "callback",
      success: function(data) {
        name = data.display_name;
        logo = data.logo;
        console.log('channel data below:')
        console.log(name);


        $("body").append(
          "<div id=" +
          name +
          "Container>" +
          ' <span class ="icon" id =' +
          name +
          "><img src=" +
          data.logo +
          ">" +
          "</span>" +
          '<span class = "status" id = "' +
          name +
          'data"></span>' +
          "</div>"
        );
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: twitchUrlStream,
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonp: "callback",
          success: function(data) {
            console.log('stream data below:')

            console.log(name);

            if (data.stream === null) {
              $("#" + name + "data").html( 
                " " + 
                '<a target = "_blank" href ="https://www.twitch.tv/' +
                name +
                '">' +
                name +
                "</a>" +
                " is currently offline"
              );
            } else {
              $("#" + name + "data").html(
                " " +
                '<a target = "_blank" href ="https://www.twitch.tv/' +
                data.stream.channel.display_name +
                '">' +
                data.stream.channel.display_name +
                "</a>" +
                " is Streaming: " +
                data.stream.game +
                "-- " +
                data.stream.channel.status
              );
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thats why [then is here](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of solving this is with promises. I have quickly promisified your jquery with $.when, and have fixed your page.

There are a few problems with your code. There was a variable not declared with var so it created a global variable, so you always only got the latest http get value.

I have used the "let" keyword to declare variables and put them inside the for loop. This creates a local variable that is only valid within each loop and is not over written. The for loop uses as a counter variable "i" which also is not declared so this also becomes a global variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

```
$.when(your ajax code)
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Qrbzqx

This creates an object with the two responses in the one object. You can now use this to write your HTML to the Document

notice the .then() these are triggered after each http get

Comment: I defined the problematic variables inside the for loop with "let' as you did and it seems to work even without using promises. Is this behavior expected? Are promised not required in this case?

Comment: Yes your variables locations are probably what caused the problem, because the value stored would be the most recent value, however it is worth learning promises. It makes async operations a lot easier. Please accept my answer, as it my first successful answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is it possible to use `var` and not `let`? I assume there is a way to use `var` and keep it local scope?

Comment: Yes that is fine, Let and Const are only syntax sugar for var anyways. I would recommend you learn ES6 next as your code is ok and your ready to move onto it. It will make things a lot easier. Thanks for selecting answered